# Determine the size of an array in Java based on the value of a variable

Tags: java, arrays

Is it possible to program something along the lines of this:

```
// Variables
int numMonths = 0; 
int numYears = 0; 
double [] interestAccurred = new double[numMonths];
double [] compoundMonthly = new double[numMonths];
// Convert years into months
numMonths = (numYears * 12) ;
```

For example, lets say a user inputs into a program 2 years. The program converts that to months (24 to be exact). Then I want the arrays interestAccurred and compoundMonthly to have 24 positions (0 - 23). Would that be possible? Thanks.

Comment: It will work if you calculate `numMonths` **before** you define your arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible. To get the input of user you can use [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

to read an `int` you can use `nextInt()`:

```
int numYears = sc.nextInt();
```

then do the computations, and create/initialize the arrays:

```
int numMonths = numYears * 2;

double[] interestAccurred = new double[numMonths];
double[] compoundMonthly = new double[numMonths];
// ...
```

**Note:** You can use `Scanner` to read `int`, `float`, `double`, `String`...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. However, you have the line

```
numMonths = (numYears * 12);
```

*after* the array declarations. This is incorrect. It should come *before*, like this:

```
int numMonths = 0; 
int numYears = 0;
numMonths = (numYears * 12);
double[] interestAccurred = new double[numMonths];
double[] compoundMonthly = new double[numMonths];
```

If you reassign the value of numMonths *after* the array declarations, the array size will not automatically change, because primitives are passed by *value*, not by reference. You must set numMonths to the desired array size, and then declare the arrays.

Moreover, Java arrays are of fixed size. Once you declare the size, it cannot be changed.